# Is it possible that I ask this question here

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is it possible that I ask [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/a-question-about-the-math-courses-to-take) question here ? I already asked it on academia SE, but I am getting downvotes. I don't know why. Perhaps its because the percentage of "math-oriented" users  in academia users is probably much less than that of mathematics SE. Perhaps there is something wrong with my question , but I don't see it.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either... but asking it here would normally (i.e., without knowing it's already a crosspost from Academia) result in people pointing you to Academia.SE. After all, it's not about the maths but about the bureaucracy surrounding it.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanks for your reply. Would it be OK if I ask it here ? or just wait till I get an answer on academia SE if I ever get

Comment: IMHO it's off-topic to MSE, so I won't advise you to post it. But I didn't put my reply as an answer because I do understand the sentiment and think you should get an answer. So I'm a bit ambivalent, really.

Comment: @Lord_Farin OK. If you have any answers to my question, please post them. Tthanks

Comment: Something I found odd about the question: The courses you list are actually books and their authors, not courses.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes the courses will be based on the books mentioned

Answer (score 2):

My *personal* opinion is that the question is too localised. Without knowing a lot more about you it is hard to give a good answer. And with knowing a lot more about you, this question will hardly help anyone else in the future. You are much better off consulting an academic advisor at your institution or some professors in private.

In short, I don't think posting this question would be a great use of this site.

---

As to why this question is getting downvotes at Academia.SE: that should be asked at meta.Academia, not here.